# MongoDB PHP Driver install failed (Windows)

Tags: mongodb

I attempted to download the `php_mongo.dll` from this link (http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads) and added the extension to php. However it doesn't work at all.

My PHP version is: 5.2.x
Windows: Windows 7 64 bit.

I have also try to use pecl install mongo but it returned some error like:

> This DSP mongo.dsp doesn't not exist.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I find I got the problem. I download a non-thread-save binary and that's why it can't be started.